# Finding unique keys

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, hash-map

I made the following snippet. It finds unique keys based on their values. For all keys \$s\$ that are contained in another key \$D\$ with the same value, key \$s\$ is discarded and key \$D\$ is returned.

```
newdict = {}

for key1, value1 in mydict.items():
  for key2, value2 in mydict.items():
    if ((key1 in key2) and (value1 == value2)):
      if key1 in newdict:
        del newdict[key1]
      newdict[key2] = value2

print(newdict)
```

```
>>> mydict = {'d': 10, 'k': 10, 'n': 10, 'p': 10, 'j': 10, 'e': 10, 'q': 10, 'f': 10, 'z': 10, 'a': 10, 'i': 10, 'm': 10, 'o': 10, 'dk': 10, 'kn': 10, 'np': 10, 'pj': 10, 'je': 10, 'ek': 10, 'kq': 10, 'qf': 10, 'fp': 10, 'pd': 10, 'nz': 10, 'zq': 10, 'qj': 10, 'ja': 9, 'ap': 10, 'df': 10, 'fn': 10, 'nd': 10, 'ff': 10, 'fj': 10, 'jn': 10, 'nq': 10, 'qd': 10, 'di': 10, 'if': 10, 'nj': 10, 'jm': 10, 'mm': 10, 'ma': 10, 'af': 10, 'fm': 10, 'mf': 10, 'fi': 10, 'id': 10, 'dd': 10, 'da': 10, 'an': 10, 'dq': 10, 'qa': 10, 'jj': 10, 'jd': 10, 'dp': 10, 'pq': 10, 'de': 10, 'ei': 10, 'ik': 10, 'kp': 10, 'pa': 10, 'ad': 10, 'en': 10, 'nn': 10, 'pi': 10, 'ii': 10, 'io': 10, 'od': 10, 'do': 10, 'oz': 10, 'zp': 10, 'eq': 10, 'fd': 10, 'qz': 10, 'am': 10, 'mq': 9, 'fe': 10, 'dn': 10, 'ne': 10, 'ea': 10, 'no': 9, 'oi': 10, 'mi': 10, 'om': 10, 'md': 10, 'dj': 10, 'jf': 10, 'nk': 10, 'ka': 10, 'aa': 10, 'ak': 10, 'kf': 10, 'of': 10, 'pz': 10, 'po': 10, 'oa': 10, 'ee': 10, 'qe': 10, 'eo': 10, 'oo': 10, 'oq': 10, 'qq': 10, 'qk': 10, 'kd': 10, 'nm': 10, 'az': 10, 'zk': 10, 'pe': 10, 'fz': 10, 'ze': 10, 'ef': 10, 'fo': 10, 'dm': 10, 'mk': 10, 'kk': 10, 'kj': 9, 'jk': 10, 'qo': 10, 'qn': 10, 'na': 10, 'ai': 10, 'iq': 10, 'aq': 10, 'fk': 10, 'jp': 10, 'za': 10, 'mp': 10, 'qp': 9, 'pm': 10, 'pn': 10, 'ko': 9, 'op': 10, 'dz': 10, 'ed': 10, 'em': 10, 'jo': 10, 'mz': 10, 'zo': 9, 'km': 10, 'mj': 10, 'ke': 10, 'ej': 10, 'zm': 10, 'kz': 10, 'oj': 10, 'qi': 9, 'mn': 10, 'in': 10, 'iz': 10, 'zz': 10, 'zj': 9, 'pf': 10, 'fq': 10, 'qm': 10, 'me': 10, 'nf': 10, 'ie': 9, 'aj': 10, 'fa': 10, 'ni': 10, 'ae': 10, 'zd': 10, 'zn': 10, 'ia': 9, 'ao': 10, 'ok': 10, 'oe': 10, 'ij': 9, 'zi': 10, 'ji': 9, 'ep': 9, 'ki': 10, 'zf': 10, 'im': 9, 'ip': 10, 'mo': 10, 'ez': 10, 'jz': 9, 'on': 10, 'pk': 10, 'jq': 10, 'pp': 9, 'dkn': 5, 'npj': 4, 'pje': 4, 'jek': 4, 'kqf': 5, 'qfp': 4, 'fpd': 7, 'pdk': 4, 'qja': 5, 'jap': 4, 'apd': 4, 'pdf': 9, 'dfn': 9, 'fnd': 10, 'ndf': 7, 'dff': 8, 'ffj': 6, 'fjn': 7, 'jnq': 5, 'nqd': 6, 'qdi': 8, 'dif': 9, 'maf': 4, 'afm': 5, 'fmf': 5, 'mfi': 7, 'fid': 9, 'idd': 8, 'dda': 10, 'dan': 6, 'anp': 4, 'npd': 6, 'pdq': 4, 'qap': 5, 'dqj': 5, 'jjd': 5, 'jdp': 4, 'dpq': 6, 'pqd': 6, 'qde': 8, 'dei': 6, 'ikp': 5, 'pad': 6, 'adq': 4, 'dqd': 10, 'den': 5, 'enn': 4, 'pii': 4, 'iod': 5, 'odo': 5, 'doz': 7, 'deq': 7, 'qfd': 6, 'fdq': 7, 'dqz': 8, 'zpa': 7, 'eid': 7, 'idn': 8, 'dne': 5, 'nea': 4, 'oid': 7, 'ddd': 10, 'dam': 5, 'omd': 6, 'mdj': 6, 'djf': 6, 'jfn': 5, 'fnk': 7, 'aak': 4, 'akf': 5, 'kfd': 7, 'fdf': 10, 'dfp': 10, 'qdd': 8, 'ddo': 10, 'dof': 8, 'ofd': 10, 'fdp': 10, 'dpz': 7, 'poa': 6, 'oad': 8, 'ade': 6, 'dee': 6, 'ead': 8, 'adj': 5, 'djd': 10, 'jdq': 5, 'dqe': 6, 'qka': 5, 'akd': 6, 'kdq': 7, 'qdj': 4, 'jdn': 4, 'dnm': 6, 'nmd': 4, 'mda': 8, 'daz': 6, 'kqd': 6, 'qdp': 4, 'dpe': 7, 'ean': 4, 'njd': 5, 'jdf': 9, 'dfz': 6, 'fze': 6, 'fom': 5, 'mdp': 6, 'dpd': 8, 'pdm': 6, 'mkd': 4, 'kdk': 6, 'dkk': 8, 'kkj': 4, 'kjf': 4, 'jfj': 5, 'fjk': 6, 'jkd': 8, 'kdo': 5, 'dod': 6, 'odq': 6, 'dqo': 7, 'qod': 7, 'odf': 8, 'dfi': 8, 'fif': 6, 'iff': 7, 'aiq': 5, 'nzp': 5, 'zpd': 6, 'pdd': 9, 'ddf': 10, 'ffk': 6, 'fkj': 4, 'pid': 4, 'ddn': 10, 'dnz': 5, 'zaf': 6, 'afn': 5, 'fnm': 4, 'pqn': 5, 'qnp': 4, 'pmq': 4, 'pnp': 4, 'dko': 5, 'kof': 4, 'ofo': 4, 'fop': 5, 'opd': 4, 'fnq': 4, 'knm': 4, 'nmk': 5, 'pdz': 4, 'dze': 5, 'zed': 7, 'eda': 6, 'daa': 6, 'fde': 6, 'dem': 6, 'emq': 4, 'mqd': 4, 'djo': 5, 'opa': 5, 'paf': 4, 'afe': 4, 'eed': 6, 'edk': 4, 'dkd': 10, 'kda': 5, 'oif': 5, 'qda': 4, 'kmm': 4, 'ejf': 5, 'odz': 4, 'dzm': 6, 'zmf': 5, 'mfd': 7, 'fdd': 10, 'dfj': 8, 'fjj': 5, 'jjk': 6, 'kzo': 4, 'ojf': 4, 'jff': 4, 'ffd': 10, 'fdm': 8, 'dma': 5, 'maq': 4, 'qif': 5, 'ifo': 5, 'ofn': 6, 'fne': 5, 'ned': 6, 'ede': 8, 'ded': 10, 'edm': 8, 'dmn': 6, 'qin': 4, 'inp': 4, 'pnd': 7, 'ndi': 5, 'diz': 6, 'izz': 4, 'zjf': 6, 'jfz': 4, 'kjd': 6, 'jdm': 4, 'kde': 6, 'edj': 7, 'dfk': 7, 'fkd': 8, 'kdd': 10, 'dfd': 10, 'dfe': 7, 'fef': 7, 'eff': 6, 'dmp': 6, 'pef': 7, 'efj': 5, 'jnd': 5, 'ifd': 7, 'fda': 9, 'daq': 7, 'qqd': 5, 'jkj': 5, 'kja': 4, 'jad': 7, 'add': 10, 'ddq': 9, 'qdm': 7, 'dmd': 10, 'mdz': 5, 'fnz': 4, 'zpf': 4, 'pff': 7, 'ffq': 5, 'fqm': 4, 'ejd': 5, 'dmz': 6, 'anf': 6, 'nfd': 9, 'fdi': 8, 'noz': 4, 'jfq': 5, 'fqo': 5, 'iem': 5, 'emd': 6, 'dzk': 7, 'zkd': 6, 'daj': 6, 'ajn': 5, 'jnf': 4, 'nfa': 4, 'amd': 4, 'mdn': 7, 'dnq': 6, 'qdf': 8, 'dad': 7, 'adz': 8, 'edd': 8, 'doa': 9, 'adn': 4, 'dni': 6, 'efp': 4, 'ekd': 4, 'doq': 5, 'diq': 6, 'iqz': 4, 'qzz': 5, 'zdp': 7, 'pzz': 5, 'zdn': 5, 'dnn': 7, 'pzk': 4, 'keq': 5, 'end': 4, 'ndm': 5, 'iaa': 4, 'ajm': 5, 'jmd': 6, 'mdm': 5, 'mpd': 5, 'pde': 6, 'dea': 9, 'eak': 4, 'akz': 4, 'zjo': 5, 'jde': 5, 'enq': 5, 'nqf': 6, 'ifa': 4, 'qdq': 9, 'dqi': 7, 'qid': 4, 'idf': 7, 'fnp': 7, 'npq': 4, 'dpm': 7, 'mde': 8, 'eqo': 4, 'qoo': 4, 'oom': 5, 'odn': 4, 'enf': 5, 'nfi': 5, 'fik': 7, 'ikd': 4, 'kdp': 7, 'dpi': 6, 'ijd': 5, 'zid': 6, 'idq': 9, 'jji': 7, 'ifp': 6, 'fpz': 7, 'pzd': 5, 'zdd': 8, 'dde': 7, 'dep': 6, 'epm': 4, 'odj': 5, 'ddm': 9, 'doi': 5, 'oqe': 6, 'aoq': 4, 'dfo': 9, 'foz': 4, 'zof': 4, 'ofq': 4, 'fqe': 4, 'qef': 6, 'efk': 5, 'dnf': 8, 'nfe': 5, 'fed': 8, 'edq': 6, 'dqp': 7, 'pzf': 5, 'zfz': 6, 'zod': 5, 'oda': 6, 'dao': 8, 'aod': 9, 'dop': 10, 'dkf': 9, 'kfp': 6, 'fpi': 6, 'aio': 4, 'odd': 9, 'dnp': 6, 'edp': 4, 'piq': 5, 'pjd': 6, 'fkn': 8, 'ifq': 6, 'fqz': 6, 'qzm': 5, 'zmd': 8, 'dkm': 8, 'kmd': 7, 'nei': 4, 'pfk': 4, 'fke': 7, 'knn': 5, 'nnd': 5, 'ndd': 9, 'ddp': 9, 'mom': 4, 'zqm': 4, 'qmd': 5, 'mdf': 5, 'ffz': 7, 'edn': 4, 'odm': 5, 'fpo': 6, 'oqd': 5, 'qdk': 9, 'kdi': 6, 'din': 7, 'qfa': 4, 'faq': 4, 'aqm': 4, 'mnn': 6, 'nnq': 5, 'qdo': 6, 'odi': 7, 'die': 5, 'ezd': 6, 'zdo': 7, 'ofz': 6, 'fzd': 7, 'zdq': 5, 'azd': 5, 'dpa': 7, 'pme': 5, 'mep': 4, 'dqf': 7, 'jzq': 4, 'qzj': 4, 'zjd': 6, 'djj': 6, 'jef': 7, 'efd': 9, 'fdz': 9, 'dzn': 5, 'nia': 4, 'iad': 5, 'zmo': 5, 'moo': 4, 'oon': 4, 'pdj': 5, 'djp': 7, 'pod': 7, 'fdn': 9, 'jpf': 5, 'pfd': 7, 'dpk': 7, 'pke': 6, 'ekk': 4, 'kkf': 8, 'kff': 5, 'fff': 7, 'fon': 6, 'qpd': 4, 'djq': 6, 'qqo': 4, 'qon': 4, 'zfn': 5, 'nke': 4, 'ked': 6, 'eod': 4, 'ode': 7, 'dez': 7, 'ezi': 4, 'imf': 6, 'mpn': 7, 'oqk': 4, 'jfd': 8, 'ifm': 5, 'fdj': 10, 'ffm': 9, 'zzk': 5, 'zkf': 5, 'kfk': 4, 'fka': 4, 'kad': 6, 'adm': 6, 'dmf': 9, 'mff': 6, 'ffn': 5, 'ffe': 6, 'efn': 4, 'nip': 4, 'ipm': 4, 'afd': 10, 'dfm': 8, 'med': 6, 'edf': 7, 'dzd': 8, 'ddk': 9, 'dkj': 4, 'dik': 7, 'ikm': 4, 'kmn': 4, 'jid': 4, 'ido': 6, 'off': 6, 'ffa': 7, 'faa': 4, 'adp': 6, 'mze': 4, 'edz': 4, 'zda': 6, 'aop': 5, 'opo': 4, 'eqd': 6, 'ppe': 4, 'pej': 4, 'jaz': 4, 'epa': 4, 'emj': 4, 'npo': 4, 'poz': 4, 'aaf': 4, 'afk': 4, 'knd': 6, 'dna': 4, 'nqq': 4, 'dnj': 4, 'aff': 5, 'qei': 5, 'idm': 7, 'okp': 6, 'qff': 6, 'epn': 4, 'qjf': 5, 'did': 8, 'odp': 5, 'dpj': 6, 'qkm': 5, 'moj': 5, 'ojd': 5, 'edo': 7, 'dok': 6, 'oki': 4, 'fjd': 8, 'nmz': 4, 'nfn': 4, 'mak': 5, 'dzp': 5, 'kno': 4, 'ozd': 8, 'ddz': 9, 'dzf': 7, 'dej': 5, 'iqf': 4, 'iin': 4, 'ind': 6, 'ndp': 4, 'kzd': 5, 'zdf': 8, 'onf': 5, 'fqd': 8, 'dij': 5, 'mpf': 6, 'ffi': 5, 'ife': 9, 'doo': 7, 'ooe': 4, 'nif': 7, 'ifi': 5, 'ide': 6, 'kdf': 8, 'zfm': 4, 'fmd': 6, 'oai': 4, 'aif': 4, 'ifj': 6, 'fja': 4, 'jai': 5, 'qnd': 6, 'fod': 6, 'fae': 6, 'nkf': 6, 'zno': 5, 'qkd': 5, 'dqn': 5, 'nek': 4, 'kak': 5, 'kid': 6, 'idj': 8, 'dji': 6, 'pni': 4, 'nid': 6, 'idz': 5, 'fmn': 4, 'fpn': 5, 'nad': 8, 'mnd': 6, 'dpp': 6, 'ppd': 6, 'dkp': 4, 'pmj': 5, 'jkq': 4, 'qfk': 4, 'zqd': 7, 'zfj': 6, 'fjm': 4, 'ien': 4, 'nod': 5, 'fzp': 4, 'ina': 5, 'jdz': 5, 'zdi': 8, 'dia': 6, 'ndq': 5, 'fdk': 9, 'kmq': 5, 'jof': 4, 'pfq': 4, 'fqi': 4, 'njz': 4, 'zme': 6, 'mef': 5, 'efi': 4, 'fqf': 5, 'epd': 4, 'pda': 7, 'dmo': 6, 'mod': 6, 'zdm': 4, 'dmm': 4, 'mmo': 5, 'mon': 4, 'oni': 4, 'jdd': 8, 'ddi': 7, 'ffp': 6, 'fjf': 8, 'jfm': 6, 'odk': 4, 'dkz': 8, 'jmf': 4, 'aed': 7, 'dkq': 5, 'qfz': 5, 'mko': 4, 'okn': 5, 'dpo': 6, 'dnd': 8, 'ndo': 7, 'don': 5, 'aan': 5, 'fkq': 4, 'def': 6, 'fnn': 5, 'nnf': 6, 'pjk': 4, 'mfa': 6, 'fao': 5, 'nao': 5, 'aoi': 5, 'naj': 5, 'ied': 7, 'jzo': 4, 'fen': 5, 'iif': 5, 'jnn': 7, 'nne': 6, 'fqa': 5, 'apf': 5, 'aei': 5, 'idp': 7, 'zji': 4, 'jqf': 5, 'eai': 4, 'ijj': 4, 'iao': 6, 'deo': 4, 'ooz': 4, 'ozm': 4, 'oin': 4, 'ndz': 6, 'fje': 4, 'fdo': 6, 'iqd': 6, 'pfj': 4, 'dqm': 6, 'fan': 5, 'zfo': 5, 'ooj': 4, 'fof': 7, 'epj': 4, 'jdi': 7, 'pdo': 8, 'edi': 6, 'ika': 4, 'ajf': 5, 'jfp': 6, 'fpk': 8, 'pka': 4, 'ook': 4, 'pfa': 5, 'fad': 8, 'nqn': 5, 'aqd': 6, 'aee': 4, 'ema': 4, 'fej': 4, 'nfp': 6, 'njf': 5, 'fmo': 4, 'oef': 4, 'qdz': 5, 'zmp': 5, 'ejm': 4, 'jmj': 5, 'mjf': 4, 'jfe': 4, 'dfq': 7, 'pmp': 4, 'ozf': 4, 'zff': 6, 'fmk': 5, 'dae': 7, 'oed': 4, 'zjn': 4, 'kif': 4, 'zna': 5, 'fzf': 5, 'zfd': 7, 'nef': 5, 'efq': 4, 'fqk': 4, 'pmf': 4, 'mfe': 4, 'ond': 7, 'dpn': 6, 'pnf': 6, 'nfz': 4, 'pnk': 5, 'nkd': 6, 'fmm': 5, 'ipd': 5, 'ado': 6, 'oaf': 5, 'qzi': 4, 'adk': 6, 'dqq': 4, 'ada': 5, 'azn': 4, 'znf': 5, 'fii': 6, 'pfo': 5, 'kpf': 4, 'fkk': 4, 'kkd': 5, 'dqk': 4, 'ijk': 5, 'mnz': 5, 'kpd': 6, 'dai': 5, 'aip': 4, 'efa': 6, 'pdi': 5, 'zem': 4, 'emf': 4, 'dza': 5, 'dio': 6, 'iof': 4, 'omi': 4, 'mid': 6, 'daf': 8, 'afp': 4, 'fpe': 6, 'efz': 5, 'ekp': 4, 'pdp': 7, 'zif': 6, 'kjk': 4, 'koo': 4, 'kfe': 5, 'ddj': 6, 'dja': 5, 'mdd': 5, 'djn': 6, 'kem': 4, 'pdn': 5, 'ndn': 4, 'nmf': 4, 'okd': 4, 'kdn': 5, 'znm': 4, 'afi': 7, 'fie': 5, 'eij': 4, 'inn': 4, 'nna': 5, 'nan': 4, 'kqp': 5, 'ndk': 5, 'kmp': 5, 'pmz': 4, 'mzf': 4, 'dfa': 7, 'qmz': 4, 'mzd': 4, 'zfi': 4, 'iid': 4, 'dka': 5, 'qof': 4, 'kpe': 4, 'pkf': 6, 'kqa': 4, 'qaj': 5, 'mfj': 5, 'dki': 4, 'foj': 4, 'knj': 4, 'nzj': 6, 'jpn': 4, 'aie': 5, 'ief': 4, 'qak': 4, 'oof': 5, 'ofi': 4, 'fiq': 4, 'qdn': 6, 'pnz': 4, 'nze': 4, 'zfp': 4, 'nzf': 4, 'nff': 5, 'mfq': 4, 'fqn': 4, 'mdi': 6, 'amm': 6, 'izd': 7, 'kzf': 5, 'jda': 7, 'amo': 4, 'fmi': 6, 'ikf': 4, 'nmn': 5, 'nzd': 6, 'mad': 4, 'adi': 4, 'dip': 7, 'mkk': 5, 'qnn': 4, 'pik': 4, 'ipo': 4, 'nde': 4, 'emp': 4, 'mpk': 4, 'qmj': 5, 'nnk': 5, 'nkm': 4, 'qfm': 5, 'dom': 5, 'ini': 4, 'adf': 5, 'faf': 6, 'djm': 5, 'fai': 4, 'aid': 5, 'idi': 4, 'ajd': 5, 'jdo': 5, 'kpo': 4, 'pfi': 4, 'fmp': 4, 'zqa': 5, 'qoe': 4, 'ikk': 4, 'jqd': 4, 'kmf': 4, 'ofm': 4, 'eii': 4, 'iip': 4, 'iqe': 4, 'qea': 5, 'and': 4, 'mqq': 4, 'kfn': 4, 'mei': 5, 'oja': 4, 'jam': 4, 'mpm': 4, 'iej': 4, 'kkn': 4, 'zde': 4, 'eie': 4, 'fzn': 4, 'zdk': 4, 'eaf': 5, 'fjq': 4, 'mfn': 5, 'mzm': 5, 'qaf': 4, 'nda': 5, 'dpf': 6, 'aoa': 4, 'afq': 4, 'qoj': 4, 'eje': 4, 'ppz': 4, 'znd': 5, 'pjn': 4, 'opn': 4, 'fiz': 4, 'qmf': 4, 'qed': 4, 'kmi': 4, 'aad': 4, 'fkm': 4, 'mdq': 5, 'mjd': 4, 'dke': 4, 'dap': 4, 'pjf': 6, 'mop': 5, 'mpj': 5, 'ofa': 4, 'fem': 4, 'eof': 5, 'pkd': 4, 'pkq': 4, 'qpk': 4, 'dfnd': 5, 'fndf': 4, 'iddd': 5, 'ddda': 6, 'poad': 5, 'mdpd': 4, 'fjkd': 4, 'dfif': 4, 'zpdd': 4, 'ddff': 4, 'dddn': 5, 'dzed': 4, 'fddf': 6, 'djdf': 4, 'fkdd': 4, 'ddfd': 5, 'dfdf': 6, 'fdfe': 4, 'difd': 4, 'dzkd': 4, 'qdfd': 4, 'fdfd': 6, 'dfda': 4, 'doad': 4, 'ijdf': 4, 'dqdd': 6, 'dnfe': 4, 'daod': 5, 'dddm': 5, 'qdqd': 4, 'zddd': 5, 'dddd': 8, 'dddp': 5, 'fdfj': 4, 'jefd': 4, 'fdzn': 4, 'dfdn': 5, 'fdnf': 5, 'fdda': 4, 'dpke': 4, 'mafd': 4, 'dffd': 5, 'dzdo': 4, 'idmd': 4, 'dedd': 4, 'ifed': 4, 'dddk': 5, 'ddkd': 4, 'dkdf': 4, 'dfdd': 5, 'fddp': 5, 'ddpk': 5, 'ndfo': 4, 'efdd': 5, 'nddd': 6, 'dppd': 4, 'dadd': 4, 'ddmo': 4, 'ddqd': 4, 'dqdf': 4, 'ffmd': 4, 'mfan': 4, 'dfdk': 4, 'fdkd': 6, 'oddd': 4, 'didd': 4, 'ddaf': 6, 'ffdd': 4, 'dkmp': 4, 'fdid': 4, 'idnd': 4, 'didp': 5, 'addz': 5, 'kzfd': 4, 'dffm': 4, 'pdfd': 4, 'dddf': 4, 'ofdd': 6, 'fmdp': 4, 'ddkk': 4, 'dndd': 4, 'ddkf': 6, 'fjdf': 4, 'dfpk': 5, 'ndad': 4, 'fddd': 5, 'idfd': 4, 'dfdfd': 4, 'ndddd': 4}
>>> ...
{'kn': 10, 'np': 10, 'pj': 10, 'je': 10, 'ek': 10, 'kq': 10, 'qf': 10, 'pd': 10, 'nz': 10, 'zq': 10, 'qj': 10, 'ja': 9, 'ap': 10, 'fj': 10, 'jn': 10, 'nq': 10, 'di': 10, 'if': 10, 'nj': 10, 'jm': 10, 'mm': 10, 'ma': 10, 'fm': 10, 'mf': 10, 'fi': 10, 'id': 10, 'an': 10, 'qa': 10, 'jj': 10, 'pq': 10, 'ei': 10, 'ik': 10, 'kp': 10, 'pa': 10, 'en': 10, 'nn': 10, 'pi': 10, 'ii': 10, 'io': 10, 'od': 10, 'oz': 10, 'zp': 10, 'eq': 10, 'qz': 10, 'am': 10, 'mq': 9, 'fe': 10, 'ne': 10, 'ea': 10, 'no': 9, 'oi': 10, 'mi': 10, 'om': 10, 'jf': 10, 'nk': 10, 'ka': 10, 'aa': 10, 'ak': 10, 'kf': 10, 'pz': 10, 'po': 10, 'oa': 10, 'ee': 10, 'qe': 10, 'eo': 10, 'oo': 10, 'oq': 10, 'qq': 10, 'qk': 10, 'nm': 10, 'az': 10, 'zk': 10, 'pe': 10, 'fz': 10, 'ze': 10, 'ef': 10, 'fo': 10, 'mk': 10, 'kk': 10, 'kj': 9, 'jk': 10, 'qo': 10, 'qn': 10, 'na': 10, 'ai': 10, 'iq': 10, 'aq': 10, 'fk': 10, 'jp': 10, 'za': 10, 'mp': 10, 'qp': 9, 'pm': 10, 'pn': 10, 'ko': 9, 'dz': 10, 'em': 10, 'jo': 10, 'mz': 10, 'zo': 9, 'km': 10, 'mj': 10, 'ke': 10, 'ej': 10, 'zm': 10, 'kz': 10, 'oj': 10, 'qi': 9, 'mn': 10, 'in': 10, 'iz': 10, 'zz': 10, 'zj': 9, 'pf': 10, 'fq': 10, 'qm': 10, 'me': 10, 'nf': 10, 'ie': 9, 'aj': 10, 'fa': 10, 'ni': 10, 'ae': 10, 'zd': 10, 'zn': 10, 'ia': 9, 'ao': 10, 'ok': 10, 'oe': 10, 'ij': 9, 'zi': 10, 'ji': 9, 'ep': 9, 'ki': 10, 'zf': 10, 'im': 9, 'ip': 10, 'mo': 10, 'ez': 10, 'jz': 9, 'on': 10, 'pk': 10, 'jq': 10, 'pp': 9, 'dkn': 5, 'npj': 4, 'pje': 4, 'jek': 4, 'kqf': 5, 'qfp': 4, 'fpd': 7, 'pdk': 4, 'qja': 5, 'jap': 4, 'apd': 4, 'pdf': 9, 'dfn': 9, 'fnd': 10, 'ndf': 7, 'dff': 8, 'ffj': 6, 'fjn': 7, 'jnq': 5, 'nqd': 6, 'qdi': 8, 'dif': 9, 'afm': 5, 'fmf': 5, 'mfi': 7, 'fid': 9, 'idd': 8, 'dda': 10, 'dan': 6, 'anp': 4, 'npd': 6, 'pdq': 4, 'qap': 5, 'dqj': 5, 'jjd': 5, 'jdp': 4, 'dpq': 6, 'pqd': 6, 'qde': 8, 'dei': 6, 'ikp': 5, 'pad': 6, 'adq': 4, 'dqd': 10, 'den': 5, 'enn': 4, 'pii': 4, 'iod': 5, 'odo': 5, 'doz': 7, 'deq': 7, 'qfd': 6, 'fdq': 7, 'dqz': 8, 'zpa': 7, 'eid': 7, 'idn': 8, 'dne': 5, 'nea': 4, 'oid': 7, 'ddd': 10, 'dam': 5, 'omd': 6, 'mdj': 6, 'djf': 6, 'jfn': 5, 'fnk': 7, 'aak': 4, 'akf': 5, 'kfd': 7, 'fdf': 10, 'dfp': 10, 'qdd': 8, 'ddo': 10, 'dof': 8, 'ofd': 10, 'fdp': 10, 'dpz': 7, 'poa': 6, 'oad': 8, 'ade': 6, 'dee': 6, 'ead': 8, 'adj': 5, 'djd': 10, 'jdq': 5, 'dqe': 6, 'qka': 5, 'akd': 6, 'kdq': 7, 'qdj': 4, 'jdn': 4, 'dnm': 6, 'nmd': 4, 'mda': 8, 'daz': 6, 'kqd': 6, 'qdp': 4, 'dpe': 7, 'ean': 4, 'njd': 5, 'jdf': 9, 'dfz': 6, 'fze': 6, 'fom': 5, 'mdp': 6, 'dpd': 8, 'pdm': 6, 'mkd': 4, 'kdk': 6, 'dkk': 8, 'kkj': 4, 'kjf': 4, 'jfj': 5, 'fjk': 6, 'jkd': 8, 'kdo': 5, 'dod': 6, 'odq': 6, 'dqo': 7, 'qod': 7, 'odf': 8, 'dfi': 8, 'fif': 6, 'iff': 7, 'aiq': 5, 'nzp': 5, 'zpd': 6, 'pdd': 9, 'ddf': 10, 'ffk': 6, 'fkj': 4, 'pid': 4, 'ddn': 10, 'dnz': 5, 'zaf': 6, 'afn': 5, 'fnm': 4, 'pqn': 5, 'qnp': 4, 'pmq': 4, 'pnp': 4, 'dko': 5, 'kof': 4, 'ofo': 4, 'fop': 5, 'opd': 4, 'fnq': 4, 'knm': 4, 'nmk': 5, 'pdz': 4, 'dze': 5, 'zed': 7, 'eda': 6, 'daa': 6, 'fde': 6, 'dem': 6, 'emq': 4, 'mqd': 4, 'djo': 5, 'opa': 5, 'paf': 4, 'afe': 4, 'eed': 6, 'edk': 4, 'dkd': 10, 'kda': 5, 'oif': 5, 'qda': 4, 'kmm': 4, 'ejf': 5, 'odz': 4, 'dzm': 6, 'zmf': 5, 'mfd': 7, 'fdd': 10, 'dfj': 8, 'fjj': 5, 'jjk': 6, 'kzo': 4, 'ojf': 4, 'jff': 4, 'ffd': 10, 'fdm': 8, 'dma': 5, 'maq': 4, 'qif': 5, 'ifo': 5, 'ofn': 6, 'fne': 5, 'ned': 6, 'ede': 8, 'ded': 10, 'edm': 8, 'dmn': 6, 'qin': 4, 'inp': 4, 'pnd': 7, 'ndi': 5, 'diz': 6, 'izz': 4, 'zjf': 6, 'jfz': 4, 'kjd': 6, 'jdm': 4, 'kde': 6, 'edj': 7, 'dfk': 7, 'fkd': 8, 'kdd': 10, 'dfd': 10, 'dfe': 7, 'fef': 7, 'eff': 6, 'dmp': 6, 'pef': 7, 'efj': 5, 'jnd': 5, 'ifd': 7, 'fda': 9, 'daq': 7, 'qqd': 5, 'jkj': 5, 'kja': 4, 'jad': 7, 'add': 10, 'ddq': 9, 'qdm': 7, 'dmd': 10, 'mdz': 5, 'fnz': 4, 'zpf': 4, 'pff': 7, 'ffq': 5, 'fqm': 4, 'ejd': 5, 'dmz': 6, 'anf': 6, 'nfd': 9, 'fdi': 8, 'noz': 4, 'jfq': 5, 'fqo': 5, 'iem': 5, 'emd': 6, 'dzk': 7, 'zkd': 6, 'daj': 6, 'ajn': 5, 'jnf': 4, 'nfa': 4, 'amd': 4, 'mdn': 7, 'dnq': 6, 'qdf': 8, 'dad': 7, 'adz': 8, 'edd': 8, 'doa': 9, 'adn': 4, 'dni': 6, 'efp': 4, 'ekd': 4, 'doq': 5, 'diq': 6, 'iqz': 4, 'qzz': 5, 'zdp': 7, 'pzz': 5, 'zdn': 5, 'dnn': 7, 'pzk': 4, 'keq': 5, 'end': 4, 'ndm': 5, 'iaa': 4, 'ajm': 5, 'jmd': 6, 'mdm': 5, 'mpd': 5, 'pde': 6, 'dea': 9, 'eak': 4, 'akz': 4, 'zjo': 5, 'jde': 5, 'enq': 5, 'nqf': 6, 'ifa': 4, 'qdq': 9, 'dqi': 7, 'qid': 4, 'idf': 7, 'fnp': 7, 'npq': 4, 'dpm': 7, 'mde': 8, 'eqo': 4, 'qoo': 4, 'oom': 5, 'odn': 4, 'enf': 5, 'nfi': 5, 'fik': 7, 'ikd': 4, 'kdp': 7, 'dpi': 6, 'ijd': 5, 'zid': 6, 'idq': 9, 'jji': 7, 'ifp': 6, 'fpz': 7, 'pzd': 5, 'zdd': 8, 'dde': 7, 'dep': 6, 'epm': 4, 'odj': 5, 'ddm': 9, 'doi': 5, 'oqe': 6, 'aoq': 4, 'dfo': 9, 'foz': 4, 'zof': 4, 'ofq': 4, 'fqe': 4, 'qef': 6, 'efk': 5, 'dnf': 8, 'nfe': 5, 'fed': 8, 'edq': 6, 'dqp': 7, 'pzf': 5, 'zfz': 6, 'zod': 5, 'oda': 6, 'dao': 8, 'aod': 9, 'dop': 10, 'dkf': 9, 'kfp': 6, 'fpi': 6, 'aio': 4, 'odd': 9, 'dnp': 6, 'edp': 4, 'piq': 5, 'pjd': 6, 'fkn': 8, 'ifq': 6, 'fqz': 6, 'qzm': 5, 'zmd': 8, 'dkm': 8, 'kmd': 7, 'nei': 4, 'pfk': 4, 'fke': 7, 'knn': 5, 'nnd': 5, 'ndd': 9, 'ddp': 9, 'mom': 4, 'zqm': 4, 'qmd': 5, 'mdf': 5, 'ffz': 7, 'edn': 4, 'odm': 5, 'fpo': 6, 'oqd': 5, 'qdk': 9, 'kdi': 6, 'din': 7, 'qfa': 4, 'faq': 4, 'aqm': 4, 'mnn': 6, 'nnq': 5, 'qdo': 6, 'odi': 7, 'die': 5, 'ezd': 6, 'zdo': 7, 'ofz': 6, 'fzd': 7, 'zdq': 5, 'azd': 5, 'dpa': 7, 'pme': 5, 'mep': 4, 'dqf': 7, 'jzq': 4, 'qzj': 4, 'zjd': 6, 'djj': 6, 'jef': 7, 'efd': 9, 'fdz': 9, 'dzn': 5, 'nia': 4, 'iad': 5, 'zmo': 5, 'moo': 4, 'oon': 4, 'pdj': 5, 'djp': 7, 'pod': 7, 'fdn': 9, 'jpf': 5, 'pfd': 7, 'dpk': 7, 'pke': 6, 'ekk': 4, 'kkf': 8, 'kff': 5, 'fff': 7, 'fon': 6, 'qpd': 4, 'djq': 6, 'qqo': 4, 'qon': 4, 'zfn': 5, 'nke': 4, 'ked': 6, 'eod': 4, 'ode': 7, 'dez': 7, 'ezi': 4, 'imf': 6, 'mpn': 7, 'oqk': 4, 'jfd': 8, 'ifm': 5, 'fdj': 10, 'ffm': 9, 'zzk': 5, 'zkf': 5, 'kfk': 4, 'fka': 4, 'kad': 6, 'adm': 6, 'dmf': 9, 'mff': 6, 'ffn': 5, 'ffe': 6, 'efn': 4, 'nip': 4, 'ipm': 4, 'afd': 10, 'dfm': 8, 'med': 6, 'edf': 7, 'dzd': 8, 'ddk': 9, 'dkj': 4, 'dik': 7, 'ikm': 4, 'kmn': 4, 'jid': 4, 'ido': 6, 'off': 6, 'ffa': 7, 'faa': 4, 'adp': 6, 'mze': 4, 'edz': 4, 'zda': 6, 'aop': 5, 'opo': 4, 'eqd': 6, 'ppe': 4, 'pej': 4, 'jaz': 4, 'epa': 4, 'emj': 4, 'npo': 4, 'poz': 4, 'aaf': 4, 'afk': 4, 'knd': 6, 'dna': 4, 'nqq': 4, 'dnj': 4, 'aff': 5, 'qei': 5, 'idm': 7, 'okp': 6, 'qff': 6, 'epn': 4, 'qjf': 5, 'did': 8, 'odp': 5, 'dpj': 6, 'qkm': 5, 'moj': 5, 'ojd': 5, 'edo': 7, 'dok': 6, 'oki': 4, 'fjd': 8, 'nmz': 4, 'nfn': 4, 'mak': 5, 'dzp': 5, 'kno': 4, 'ozd': 8, 'ddz': 9, 'dzf': 7, 'dej': 5, 'iqf': 4, 'iin': 4, 'ind': 6, 'ndp': 4, 'kzd': 5, 'zdf': 8, 'onf': 5, 'fqd': 8, 'dij': 5, 'mpf': 6, 'ffi': 5, 'ife': 9, 'doo': 7, 'ooe': 4, 'nif': 7, 'ifi': 5, 'ide': 6, 'kdf': 8, 'zfm': 4, 'fmd': 6, 'oai': 4, 'aif': 4, 'ifj': 6, 'fja': 4, 'jai': 5, 'qnd': 6, 'fod': 6, 'fae': 6, 'nkf': 6, 'zno': 5, 'qkd': 5, 'dqn': 5, 'nek': 4, 'kak': 5, 'kid': 6, 'idj': 8, 'dji': 6, 'pni': 4, 'nid': 6, 'idz': 5, 'fmn': 4, 'fpn': 5, 'nad': 8, 'mnd': 6, 'dpp': 6, 'ppd': 6, 'dkp': 4, 'pmj': 5, 'jkq': 4, 'qfk': 4, 'zqd': 7, 'zfj': 6, 'fjm': 4, 'ien': 4, 'nod': 5, 'fzp': 4, 'ina': 5, 'jdz': 5, 'zdi': 8, 'dia': 6, 'ndq': 5, 'fdk': 9, 'kmq': 5, 'jof': 4, 'pfq': 4, 'fqi': 4, 'njz': 4, 'zme': 6, 'mef': 5, 'efi': 4, 'fqf': 5, 'epd': 4, 'pda': 7, 'dmo': 6, 'mod': 6, 'zdm': 4, 'dmm': 4, 'mmo': 5, 'mon': 4, 'oni': 4, 'jdd': 8, 'ddi': 7, 'ffp': 6, 'fjf': 8, 'jfm': 6, 'odk': 4, 'dkz': 8, 'jmf': 4, 'aed': 7, 'dkq': 5, 'qfz': 5, 'mko': 4, 'okn': 5, 'dpo': 6, 'dnd': 8, 'ndo': 7, 'don': 5, 'aan': 5, 'fkq': 4, 'def': 6, 'fnn': 5, 'nnf': 6, 'pjk': 4, 'mfa': 6, 'fao': 5, 'nao': 5, 'aoi': 5, 'naj': 5, 'ied': 7, 'jzo': 4, 'fen': 5, 'iif': 5, 'jnn': 7, 'nne': 6, 'fqa': 5, 'apf': 5, 'aei': 5, 'idp': 7, 'zji': 4, 'jqf': 5, 'eai': 4, 'ijj': 4, 'iao': 6, 'deo': 4, 'ooz': 4, 'ozm': 4, 'oin': 4, 'ndz': 6, 'fje': 4, 'fdo': 6, 'iqd': 6, 'pfj': 4, 'dqm': 6, 'fan': 5, 'zfo': 5, 'ooj': 4, 'fof': 7, 'epj': 4, 'jdi': 7, 'pdo': 8, 'edi': 6, 'ika': 4, 'ajf': 5, 'jfp': 6, 'fpk': 8, 'pka': 4, 'ook': 4, 'pfa': 5, 'fad': 8, 'nqn': 5, 'aqd': 6, 'aee': 4, 'ema': 4, 'fej': 4, 'nfp': 6, 'njf': 5, 'fmo': 4, 'oef': 4, 'qdz': 5, 'zmp': 5, 'ejm': 4, 'jmj': 5, 'mjf': 4, 'jfe': 4, 'dfq': 7, 'pmp': 4, 'ozf': 4, 'zff': 6, 'fmk': 5, 'dae': 7, 'oed': 4, 'zjn': 4, 'kif': 4, 'zna': 5, 'fzf': 5, 'zfd': 7, 'nef': 5, 'efq': 4, 'fqk': 4, 'pmf': 4, 'mfe': 4, 'ond': 7, 'dpn': 6, 'pnf': 6, 'nfz': 4, 'pnk': 5, 'nkd': 6, 'fmm': 5, 'ipd': 5, 'ado': 6, 'oaf': 5, 'qzi': 4, 'adk': 6, 'dqq': 4, 'ada': 5, 'azn': 4, 'znf': 5, 'fii': 6, 'pfo': 5, 'kpf': 4, 'fkk': 4, 'kkd': 5, 'dqk': 4, 'ijk': 5, 'mnz': 5, 'kpd': 6, 'dai': 5, 'aip': 4, 'efa': 6, 'pdi': 5, 'zem': 4, 'emf': 4, 'dza': 5, 'dio': 6, 'iof': 4, 'omi': 4, 'mid': 6, 'daf': 8, 'afp': 4, 'fpe': 6, 'efz': 5, 'ekp': 4, 'pdp': 7, 'zif': 6, 'kjk': 4, 'koo': 4, 'kfe': 5, 'ddj': 6, 'dja': 5, 'mdd': 5, 'djn': 6, 'kem': 4, 'pdn': 5, 'ndn': 4, 'nmf': 4, 'okd': 4, 'kdn': 5, 'znm': 4, 'afi': 7, 'fie': 5, 'eij': 4, 'inn': 4, 'nna': 5, 'nan': 4, 'kqp': 5, 'ndk': 5, 'kmp': 5, 'pmz': 4, 'mzf': 4, 'dfa': 7, 'qmz': 4, 'mzd': 4, 'zfi': 4, 'iid': 4, 'dka': 5, 'qof': 4, 'kpe': 4, 'pkf': 6, 'kqa': 4, 'qaj': 5, 'mfj': 5, 'dki': 4, 'foj': 4, 'knj': 4, 'nzj': 6, 'jpn': 4, 'aie': 5, 'ief': 4, 'qak': 4, 'oof': 5, 'ofi': 4, 'fiq': 4, 'qdn': 6, 'pnz': 4, 'nze': 4, 'zfp': 4, 'nzf': 4, 'nff': 5, 'mfq': 4, 'fqn': 4, 'mdi': 6, 'amm': 6, 'izd': 7, 'kzf': 5, 'jda': 7, 'amo': 4, 'fmi': 6, 'ikf': 4, 'nmn': 5, 'nzd': 6, 'mad': 4, 'adi': 4, 'dip': 7, 'mkk': 5, 'qnn': 4, 'pik': 4, 'ipo': 4, 'nde': 4, 'emp': 4, 'mpk': 4, 'qmj': 5, 'nnk': 5, 'nkm': 4, 'qfm': 5, 'dom': 5, 'ini': 4, 'adf': 5, 'faf': 6, 'djm': 5, 'fai': 4, 'aid': 5, 'idi': 4, 'ajd': 5, 'jdo': 5, 'kpo': 4, 'pfi': 4, 'fmp': 4, 'zqa': 5, 'qoe': 4, 'ikk': 4, 'jqd': 4, 'kmf': 4, 'ofm': 4, 'eii': 4, 'iip': 4, 'iqe': 4, 'qea': 5, 'and': 4, 'mqq': 4, 'kfn': 4, 'mei': 5, 'oja': 4, 'jam': 4, 'mpm': 4, 'iej': 4, 'kkn': 4, 'zde': 4, 'eie': 4, 'fzn': 4, 'zdk': 4, 'eaf': 5, 'fjq': 4, 'mfn': 5, 'mzm': 5, 'qaf': 4, 'nda': 5, 'dpf': 6, 'aoa': 4, 'afq': 4, 'qoj': 4, 'eje': 4, 'ppz': 4, 'znd': 5, 'pjn': 4, 'opn': 4, 'fiz': 4, 'qmf': 4, 'qed': 4, 'kmi': 4, 'aad': 4, 'fkm': 4, 'mdq': 5, 'mjd': 4, 'dke': 4, 'dap': 4, 'pjf': 6, 'mop': 5, 'mpj': 5, 'ofa': 4, 'fem': 4, 'eof': 5, 'pkd': 4, 'pkq': 4, 'qpk': 4, 'dfnd': 5, 'fndf': 4, 'iddd': 5, 'ddda': 6, 'poad': 5, 'mdpd': 4, 'fjkd': 4, 'dfif': 4, 'zpdd': 4, 'ddff': 4, 'dddn': 5, 'dzed': 4, 'fddf': 6, 'djdf': 4, 'fkdd': 4, 'ddfd': 5, 'dfdf': 6, 'fdfe': 4, 'difd': 4, 'dzkd': 4, 'qdfd': 4, 'fdfd': 6, 'dfda': 4, 'doad': 4, 'ijdf': 4, 'dqdd': 6, 'dnfe': 4, 'daod': 5, 'dddm': 5, 'qdqd': 4, 'zddd': 5, 'dddd': 8, 'dddp': 5, 'fdfj': 4, 'jefd': 4, 'fdzn': 4, 'dfdn': 5, 'fdnf': 5, 'fdda': 4, 'dpke': 4, 'mafd': 4, 'dffd': 5, 'dzdo': 4, 'idmd': 4, 'dedd': 4, 'ifed': 4, 'dddk': 5, 'ddkd': 4, 'dkdf': 4, 'dfdd': 5, 'fddp': 5, 'ddpk': 5, 'ndfo': 4, 'efdd': 5, 'nddd': 6, 'dppd': 4, 'dadd': 4, 'ddmo': 4, 'ddqd': 4, 'dqdf': 4, 'ffmd': 4, 'mfan': 4, 'dfdk': 4, 'fdkd': 6, 'oddd': 4, 'didd': 4, 'ddaf': 6, 'ffdd': 4, 'dkmp': 4, 'fdid': 4, 'idnd': 4, 'didp': 5, 'addz': 5, 'kzfd': 4, 'dffm': 4, 'pdfd': 4, 'dddf': 4, 'ofdd': 6, 'fmdp': 4, 'ddkk': 4, 'dndd': 4, 'ddkf': 6, 'fjdf': 4, 'dfpk': 5, 'ndad': 4, 'fddd': 5, 'idfd': 4, 'dfdfd': 4, 'ndddd': 4}
```

I would like an implementation in Python 3 that is faster and uses less memory.

Comment: That dict is tiny, barely any room for improvement. Can you provide code to generate larger dicts representative of your real data? I'm not going to put effort into that only for you to then possibly tell me that your data is totally different and I wasted my time.

Comment: @HeapOverflow, thank you for your comment. I want to assure that your time will not be wasted and your effort will be immensely appreciated. The data is exactly this way, it is the output of some components which I do not have access to. Nevertheless, I requested for larger input and output dictionaries and have edited the question to have larger input dictionary size resulting into larger output dictionary too.

Comment: You turn `{'a': 0, 'ab': 0}` into `{'ab': 0}` but turn `{'ab': 0, 'a': 0}` into `{'ab': 0, 'a': 0}`. Is that really correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct. 

Both `{'a': 0, 'ab': 0} and {'ab': 0, 'a': 0}`will be into `{'ab': 0}`, as *a* is in *ab*.

Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### O(n * d^2) solution

The original code runs in O(n^2) time. This code runs in O(n d^2) where *n* is the length of `mydict` and *d* is the length of a key. The final code is at the bottom of the post.  Here is how I got there:

First, I had the same idea as @HeapOverflow, but then decided to try another approach.  For any key, value in `mydict`, we can create all the key's substrings and build a dictionary mapping (substring, value) to a list of keys that have that substring and value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in mydict.items():
    for width in range(1, len(key) + 1):
        for start in range(len(key) + 1 - width):
            subkey = key[start:start + width]
            pair = (subkey, value)
            d[pair].append(key)
```

The outer loop runs O(n) times and the inner two loops run O(d^2) times for O(nd^2) complexity.  The desired result is then those substring, value pairs that can only be generated from one key, value pair.

```
newdict = dict(k for k,v in d.items() if len(v)==1 and k[0]==v[0])
```

For the sample data in the problem, this runs in about 8 ms compared to 85 ms for the original code.  However, it uses a lot of memory to store the lists of keys in the dict `d`.  We can reduce the memory by noting that `newdict` only depends on whether the list of keys has one, or more than one element. The new code only appends a key to the list if the list has one element.

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in mydict.items():
    for width in range(1, len(key) + 1):
        for start in range(len(key) + 1 - width):
            subkey = key[start:start + width]
            pair = (subkey, value)
            if len(d[pair]) < 2:         #### changed code
                d[pair].append(key)
                
newdict = dict(k for k,v in d.items() if len(v)==1 and k[0]==v[0])
```

This uses reduces memory about 60% and runs in about 7.5 ms.

The next step is to recognize that `d` has two kinds of entries, those whose value has a length of 1 and those that have a length > 1.  Basically, two sets. So let's try using sets: `unique` holds the unique key-value pairs; `subsumed` holds subkey-value pairs that would be subsumed by a unique key-value pair.

```
subsumed = set()
unique = set()

for key, value in mydict.items():
    if key in subsumed:
        continue

    unique.add((key, value))
    
    for width in range(1, len(key)):
        for start in range(len(key) + 1 - width):
            subkey = key[start:start + width]
            pair = (subkey, value)
            subsumed.add(pair)
            unique.discard(pair)
            
newdict = dict(unique)
```

This runs in about 6 ms.

#### Final code

Lastly, `dict.items()` returns a view.  If the values are hashable, then `dict.items()` can be used like a set and the code can be simplified to:

```
subsumed = set()

for key, value in mydict.items():
    for width in range(1, len(key)):
        for start in range(len(key) + 1 - width):
            subkey = key[start:start + width]
            pair = (subkey, value)
            subsumed.add(pair)
            
newdict = dict(mydict.items() - subsumed)
```

This runs in about 5 ms.

#### Bug in original code

There is a probable bug in both the original code, in that the results depend on the order of iteration of the key-value pairs in `mydict.items()`.  For Python >= 3.7 the order is the same as the insertion order.  For earlier versions, the order is undefined or random.

For example, for both codes:

```
mydict = {'a':1, 'aa':1} ==> results in newdict = {'aa':1}.
```

But

```
mydict = {'aa':1, 'a':1} ==> results in newdict ={'aa':1, 'a':1}.
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I commented under the question already. And it's one reason I didn't try further improvements, intentionally keeping the logic as is because the textual task description isn't quite clear to me and there's no guarantee (or *anything* said) about the input order. But I think our codes are correct as long as the keys are sorted by increasing length, which they are in the example data (which should be representative of the real data).

Comment: @HeapOverflow For Python >= 3.7, the codes are okay as long as the keys are inserted in order of increasing length.  For Python < 3.7 the order of iteration is arbitrary so there may be errors.

Comment: Ah right, we've had 3.7 for so long now that I usually don't even think about that anymore :-P

Comment: If we consider the string length in the complexity, then I think we all get another factor d. Copying a substring and computing a string hash aren't O(1).

Comment: @HeapOverflow, sorry I didn't see you comment about the bug.  As for complexity, I was just pointing out that my inner loops are a function of key length, not the number of keys.  So the code might not be good for processing a short dictionary with long keys. Another way to look at it is O(n) with the scale factor being a function of d^2.

Comment: I am just going over the new solution but I need to quickly mention that the order of keys are always in increasing length in the input data `mydict`.

Comment: @RootTwo, this solution is fast and take lesser memory as you espoused. The probable bug is also noted but it won't be a problem as the key-value pairs in `mydict` is ordered increasingly.
I will like to clarify this, I assumed  that `d` values varies from 1 to the maximum length of keys in `mydict` and all keys with one item are not considered. Am i correct?

Comment: The first version of the code takes a key such as 'abc' and creates all possible subkeys" 'a', 'b', 'c', 'ab, 'bc', 'abc'.  `d` maps these subkeys to a list of the keys they came from.  For example after processing `{'ab':5, 'abc':5}`, 'd' would have an entry `('a',5):['ab', 'abc']`.  Run the code on a small `mydict` and then `print(d)` to see what it does.

Comment: @RootTwo, I get your explanation now. Concerning the probable bug, sorting `mydict` by key length will resolve that should in case it become inevitable.

`mydict = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda i: len(i[0]))`

This will ensure the key-value pairs are ordered increasingly.

Answer (score 2):

You try all pairs and besides comparing the keys, you check whether their values are equal. It's faster to only try pairs whose values are equal, and you can do this by first categorizing by value.

```
def filtered(mydict):
  items_for_value = {}
  for item in mydict.items():
    items_for_value.setdefault(item[1], []).append(item)

  newdict = {}

  for key1, value1 in mydict.items():
    for key2, value2 in items_for_value[value1]:   # <= changed line
      if key1 in key2:
        if key1 in newdict:
          del newdict[key1]
        newdict[key2] = value2

  return newdict
```

It's about five times as fast as your original on that larger dictionary (0.7 seconds vs 3.5 seconds).

Of course this uses *more* memory, not less.

Alternative version, categorizing just the keys, which is a bit faster and takes less extra space (but assumes it doesn't matter which of two equal `value`s we use):

```
def filtered(mydict):
  keys_for_value = {}
  for key, value in mydict.items():
    keys_for_value.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

  newdict = {}

  for key1, value in mydict.items():
    for key2 in keys_for_value[value]:
      if key1 in key2:
        if key1 in newdict:
          del newdict[key1]
        newdict[key2] = value

  return newdict
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the item tuples might get created just for me. Deleted the sentence.

Comment: @Peilonrayz It *would* be not that much more if I stored only keys instead of items, right? Far less than double then. I had actually started with that, but then worried about "equal but not identical" objects (although if they're just small ints, that should be equivalent).

Comment: The updated form would still double in space worst case - say you have `{'a': 0, 'b': 1}` then you'd make `{0: ['a'], 1: ['b']}` As you can see this contains the same amount of keys as values. We can also see you'll always double the keys, `{'a': 0, 'b': 0}` to `{0: ['a', 'b']}`. So worst case it's still double, but yes you've reduced the amount of memory.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Not sure what you mean with worst case, but I just tried, `mydict` took 52,982 bytes total and my `keys_for_value` added 5,472 bytes total, that's only 10.3% more.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "added" like your function took that much more in total or `keys_for_value` was that big? Additionally the OP's code isn't the worst case.

Comment: @Peilonrayz "Added" meaning sum of the sizes of the objects that I created in my structure (i.e., not double-counting the objects already existing in `mydict` which I'm merely referencing). See [code](https://repl.it/repls/SimilarRemarkableBucket#main.py) (numbers are higher as that's 64-bit Python, I used 32-bit Python). Not sure what you mean with the OP's code not being the worst case. Do you mean their data?

Comment: [If we just see the size of the objects](https://repl.it/repls/CostlyStingyPdf#main.py), `keys_for_value`'s size is 71392 where `mydict` is 97440. You've added 73% more memory usage. If we change to the worst case, `keys_for_value`'s size is 28865228 where `mydict` is 16491724. You've added 175% more memory usage. So your solution has almost tripled the memory usage.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Um, so you don't understand how Python uses references? It's not 73% more, it's about 10% more, as you can see with the correct code. And what you show isn't really a "worst case" but rather a *fantasy* worst case *for space*. "fantasy" because that looks nothing like the OP's data (which has very few different values), and "for space" because that's a *best* case for me *time*-wise.

Comment: Yes worst case is a fantasy 

Comment: @HeapOverflow, the `keys_for_value` works fine for me. It doesn't matter which of the two equal `value`s is used because they both represent the same thing. Thank you for both re-implementation.

Comment: @VictorAdeyemo It can perhaps be further improved by categorizing by key length as well. Most of your keys have length 3. And there's no real point in checking whether a key of length 3 contains another key of length 3. So `key2` should only go through keys with the same value *and* which are longer than `key1` (and `key1` itself). This somewhat depends on whether the keys are sorted by length, though, see also my [clarification question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249732/finding-unique-keys/249743?noredirect=1#comment489716_249732) above.

Comment: @HeapOverflow True, it doesn't make sense of check keys of the same length.